# useMemo to memoize Antd's Tree component when I manage SelectedKeys

Tags: reactjs, antd, memoization, memoise

I am using [Antd's Tree](https://3x.ant.design/components/tree/) component which takes left half of my container and the data is quite big. OnClick of any of the node, I render some details regarding the node on right half inside the container. So I load all the nodes at ones and onClick I maintain a state variable with details of the clicked node. Now since the data is big, I thought that memoizing this Tree's Functional component, I could avoid the rerender of the whole tree onClick of the node, which I am able to achieve using useMemo() but since I manage the selection of the node using Tree's prop "**selectedKeys={props.selkeys}**", the selection doesnt work but I am able to achieve that onClick the re-render doesnt happen. That is because the useMemo looks like below

```
useMemo(
() => (myTreeComp, [props.data]))
```

and if the change the useMemeo to include the selected keys also, then there is no point of memoize as it needs to rerender because the nodeselection has changed:

```
useMemo(
() => (myTreeComp, [props.data, props.selectedkeys]))
```

Since this is an existing code, i am not sure how can I solve this which not much changes.

I am also open to any other solution for this like some way to show only little data but please note all the data is loaded in a state. But please suggest any better solution.

OR

Please advice on how to use infinite-scroller or other such components with this Tree. I can't because the Tree can have only TreeNodes. Please advise.

TIA

Comment: Why not make TreeNode a pure component?

Comment: You mean wrap the TreeNode inside my pure component say MyTreeNode, but since the selectedkeys prop of Tree will be changed the Tree will rerender but MyTreeNode will re- render only one of the nodes??

Comment: That would be the idea but I could not get it to [render](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-elgamal-e2y6x?file=/index.js) because I got an error trying to create my own TreeNode saying only TreeNode can be children of Tree. Seems a bit inflexible of a UI library to not be able to wrap it's (sub) components but did not have time to see what the alternative is.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and landed into some issue. Thanks for trying. Let me know if you get a chance to try.

Comment: Even if you could somehow make TreeNode pure, the rendered part would still be in a Context.Consumer that will force re rendering whenever context changes. Using the react devtools (*Component) you can see [here](https://bflkc.csb.app/) that the first child of TreeNode is a Context.Consumer. The react devtools *Profiler shows that everything is re rendered when I change selection. This can be optimised but probably only by the creators of antd (or a pull request).

Comment: Right. While I was trying another solution where I was trying to use LazyLoad[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload] kind of solution where each TreeNode will be under :LazyLoad. But because Tree should have only TreeNode inside it, I cant do that as well, or Am i doing somethign wrong?